# Unity3d - Изменение Text через GetComponent C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, text

В сцене есть Scrolling Menu которое создает префабы с содержимым Sprite и добавлена кнопка Select и Buy которые активируются в зависимости от текущего выбора на экране в списке scrolling menu. Когда активна кнопка Buy, то используется SetActive(true) чтобы показать цену предмета в игре в виде текста на кнопке.
Пытался достать таким способом повесив скрипт на MainCamera (знаю что он кривой):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MenuBtn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int coins;
    public int PanID;
    public int SpinNum;
    public GameObject ScrollingPanel;
    public int spinNum;
    public GameObject priceInCoins;
    public GameObject PriceinCoinsT;
    public string[] PlayButtonTexts;
    public Text PlayBtnT;
    public Text coinsT;


    void Start()
    {
        PriceSpin();
        coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins", 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PanID = ScrollingPanel.GetComponent<SnapScrolling>().selectedPanID;
        coinsT.text = coins.ToString();
        ChangeSelector();
    }

    public void ChangeSelector()
    {

        if(PanID == 0)
        {
            SpinNum = 0;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(false);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[0];
        }

        if (PanID == 1)
        {
            SpinNum = 1;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }
        if (PanID == 2)
        {
            SpinNum = 2;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }
        if (PanID == 3)
        {
            SpinNum = 3;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }
        if (PanID == 4)
        {
            SpinNum = 4;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }
        if (PanID == 5)
        {
            SpinNum = 5;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }
        if (PanID == 6)
        {
            SpinNum = 6;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }
        if (PanID == 7)
        {
            SpinNum = 7;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }
        if (PanID == 8)
        {
            SpinNum = 8;
            priceInCoins.SetActive(true);
            PlayBtnT.text = PlayButtonTexts[1];
        }

    }

    public void PriceSpin()
    {
        if(SpinNum == 1)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "300";
        }
        if (SpinNum == 2)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "500";
        }
        if (SpinNum == 3)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "1000";
        }
        if (SpinNum == 4)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "1500";
        }
        if (SpinNum == 5)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "3000";
        }
        if (SpinNum == 6)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "6000";
        }
        if (SpinNum == 7)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "10000";
        }
        if (SpinNum == 8)
        {
            PriceinCoinsT.GetComponent<Text>().text = "20000";
        }

    }
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы значением selectedPanId из другого класса показывать и не показывать цену и кнопку buy/selected, но цена не изменяется.
Так вот как заставить цену меняться в зависимости от выбора в scrolling menu?

Comment: У тебя PriceSpin нигде не вызывается

Comment: Спасибо, да не заметил. а как можно связать данные текстовые значения с количеством coins игрока? ну чтобы при нажатии кнопки отнималось определенное количество coins и кнопка становилась select

Comment: If(Int.tryparse(100, out k)) {}... книжки что ли почитай какие-нибудь

Comment: вместо 100 строку вставь